# Has google ajax api just stoppped working on linux?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, certificate

I was just browsing a site I am developing and all of the sudden all the javascript stopped working. In console there is this (among uncaught reference errors caused by it):

Failed to load resource https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

If i try to put the address into url bar in chrome 18.0.1025.151, I get:

The server's security certificate is not yet valid!

If I try it under Firefox, it displays the file but loading of the file is aborted if it is included as a script in a template.

These problems are occuring only under linux. On window, everything seems fine (tried: ie, opera, firefox, chrome). What is wrong?

Comment: Loads fine here. Any there's a typo in the IP address you posted.

Comment: j08691: if you mean 18.0.1025.151 - that is my chrome version

Comment: That's not an IP address. That's his Chrome version ;).

Comment: Works fine here too. Cert is valid from April 20th through April 19th of next year.

Comment: Yes, I had set date in March 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure your system date/time is set correctly (i.e. current date) in your linux system.

Comment: You are right! The time was set two months in the past. I had no idea it can have such an impact. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that for whatever reason, the cert is being recognized as invalid. Not sure where you're working from, but many enterprise content filters end up invalidating certs. Regardless, you should be able to correct the issue by installing the cert in Chrome (essentially, saying this is okay, allow it). See [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust) for the steps.